# Connect to Oracle DB from ASP.NET on Win 2003 svr

Tags: asp.net, .net, database, vb.net, oracle

I have Visual Studio 2008 running from Windows XP.  Our server is Windows 2003 Server.

On a different server, there is an Oracle database we want to connect to.

I've made the connection work from my local VS instance using system.data.OracleClient with the following code:

```
Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=" _
                           + "(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" _
                           + "(HOST=ourHostaHere(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)" _
                           + "(SERVICE_NAME=serviceNameHere)));" _
                           + "User Id=userIdHere;Password=passwordHere;"
Using con As New OracleConnection(oradb)
Dim command As New OracleCommand("", con)
command.Connection.Open()
command.Connection.Close()
```

But... when put on our server and attempting to establish the DB connection, the following error is thrown
"System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater."

**After doing some research**, we found the following link which explains that using system.data.OracleClient is deprecated... and to use ODP.NET:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085703.html

We do not have oracle on our windows 2003 server.

---

**What do i need to do**, to get my local Visual Studio 2008 project to connect to the oracle database?

**What do i need to do**, to get our server to allow the published .NET page to connect to the oracle database?

thank you for any help with this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Step 1**: Install  Oracle10g Release 2 ODAC and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio .NET 
>     http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/dotnet/utilsoft.html
>
> **Step 2**:  Set Oracle_Home environment.  For example: Set Oracle_Home = C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1
>   **Step 3**:  Create sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora files under:  \NETWORK\ADMIN  To setup connection, you can use tnsping to test it.  For example: tnsping your_oracle_service
>   **Step 4**: Add reference Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Check this link for more info.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1146342.aspx/1

Hope it helps.